# draw lines around the image from the centroid

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

The original images [circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcZUS.jpg)

setting the image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread('blackcirr.jpg')
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5))
plt.imshow(image)
```

Finding the centroid

```
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny_edges = cv2.Canny(gray_img, 30, 200)
M = cv2.moments(canny_edges)
#calculate x,y coordinate of the center
cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])

circle = cv2.circle(image, (cx,cy), 5, (255,255,0), -1)
cv2.putText(image, "centroid", (cx -25, cy-25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,0),)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5))
line = cv2.line(image,(cx,cy), () )
plt.imshow(image)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

I wanted to draw lines that connect the centroid to points in the shape every 2 degrees or a set degree.

[Wanted Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh35K.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's necessary to use the Canny edge detection algorithm to find the centroid of the circle, a simple indexing will do.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import ceil, sin, cos, pi
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('circle.jpg', 0)
r, c = round(img.shape[0]/2), round(img.shape[1]/2)  # center row, center column
diameter = len([i for i in img[r, :] if not i])  # Count the black (circle) pixels from the middle
radius = ceil(diameter/2)

spacing = 0.5  # Can manually adjust for desired spacing
thetas = np.arange(0, 2*pi, spacing)
for theta in thetas:
    cv2.line(img, (c, r), (int(c+radius*cos(theta)), int(r+radius*sin(theta))), color=255)
plt.scatter(c, r, c='y', s=100, marker='.')
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I think I did not make myself clear, I used Canny edge to find the centroid since I wanted it to find the centroid of other shapes too, I started with the circle since it was the easiest shape to do but thank you!

Comment: @Newyenminh Oh in that case it makes total sense! So I guess in that case the ```thetas``` thing won't be of good use since you need it for a general case, is that true?

Comment: yes, I do not think the thetas would be of good use here but thank you for your help. much appreciated!